# Should sitemap index contain child sitemaps with .gz extension?

Tags: seo, xml-sitemap

**Question: Is it required to have `.gz` extension for child sitemaps or not?**

This is what I found:

Google provides the following sitemap index [example](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/75712?hl=en):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <sitemap>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/sitemap1.xml.gz</loc>
      <lastmod>2004-10-01T18:23:17+00:00</lastmod>
   </sitemap>
   <sitemap>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/sitemap2.xml.gz</loc>
      <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>
   </sitemap>
   </sitemapindex>
```

Very similar example can be found on [sitemaps.org](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#index). As per sitemaps.org:

> `<loc>` - Identifies the location of the Sitemap. This location can be a
>   Sitemap, an Atom file, RSS file or a simple text file.

Both examples don't specify anything about `.gz` and I couldn't find any sitemap index example that doesn't contain `.gz`. However, all child sitemaps in my case are not gzipped and I'm wondering whether it's right way of doing it or not.

Comment: I would suggest asking a mod to migrate this to [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com), as you're more likely to get an answer over there

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, gzipping the files is not necessary. From the [Sitemaps.org Protocol](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#index):

> **If you would like**, you may compress your Sitemap files using gzip to reduce your bandwidth requirement…

Google themselves reference uncompressed Sitemap files: https://www.google.com/sitemap.xml

Comment: Thank you for provided example! That gave me more confidence in my solution.